# Plot Multiple graph in python using matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

My CSV file looks like the one in the picture, I have plot the death_rate over the years for the first country Africa easily using the code

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import csv
f = open('000003.csv')
data = list(csv.reader(f))[0:3]
year = [i[1] for i in data[1::]]
africa_neonatal_mortality = [i[2] for i in data[1::]]
pyplot.plot(year, death rate,'r')
pyplot.title('death rate vs Year')
pyplot.xlabel('Years')
pyplot.ylabel('death rate')
pyplot.show()
```

The thing I want to do is to plot, the graph for both the death_rate and birth_rate for all countries. I am stuck at it!

Well I am a beginner to python, any help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I guess the it can all be in one command, something like `pyplot.plot(year, death rate,'r',year,birth_rate,'bs')` . Then you can modify the other details such as title and xlabel as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the it can all be in one command, something like `pyplot.plot(year, death rate,'r',year,birth_rate,'bs')` . Then you can modify the other details such as title and xlabel as necessary

Comment: ok your approach is correct birth_rate and death_rate can be in a single graph, but how i am going to cater it for multiple countries ?
Will you please help me in this regard ?

Comment: I have two suggestion, the long and unnecessary one use a `for loop`. Alternatively plot the graphs using `pandas.plot`. Load the csv using pandas.read_csv and then plot the dataframe. Should plot all of the data/columns. That's the easier and quicker option

Comment: See the following  (Read csv)[https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_dataframe_importing_csv.html] and plot (Visualization)[http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html]